# Can the angles be found?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to find the angles of a  quadrilateral when the lengths of all four sides are known and the area is known ? If not how many angles have to be known to determine the other angles ? Does anyone know of a proof for the question ?

Comment: What sort of quadrilateral are we talking about? Square, rectangle, rhombus, ...?

Comment: The quadrilateral has four different length sides

Answer (score 2):

No. If the quadrilateral has sides $2,2,1,1$ and area $1$, then there are at least three solutions, a parallelogram, a convex kite and a concave kite.